# Large Graph Visualization Library

Tags: graph, png, visualization, nodes

I need to visualize a very large graph ( > 1 million ) in a website, the library should to receive a JSON and generate a png.

I've already tried graphviz with spfd but the waiting is too long, the user will not be able to interact with a GUI so Cytoscape or Gephi are not an option.

Another option could be maybe exporting a .dot to web, but I don't know how efficient this would be.

Comment: `> 1 million` 1 million what things? ` The library should to receive a JSON` A JSON with 1 million things?? `exporting a .dot to web` What on earth does that mean? Please elaborate

Comment: Hi Gustavo. Is there a specific reason why you need a `png` export? For graph objects, especially this large, vector-based representation formats are better suited (svg, pdf...)

Comment: Sorry about not being so specific, I'd thought It might be a little obvious I'm referring to nodes. By exporting a .dot to web I mean using a tool such as [webdot](http://www.graphviz.org/pub/scm/webdot/html.in/index.html.in) to show a .dot file on a HTML canvas. It does not need to be png as long as I can display it on HTML.

I also forgot to mention that I am working with SNA that means I need to graph, nodes and their edges with a force layout. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

http://www.gnuplot.info/ and http://dygraphs.com/ are two of my favorite charting libraries for the web.  Plotting a million data points I would probably use gnuplot.  I would look at caching generated images as much as possible, perhaps even generating them in a batch rather than at the time of the request.  I think you will run into performance issues trying to pass the data in via JSON and attempting to render the graph client side.

Comment: Does gnuplot support rendering a .dot file for instance ? Can't seem to find that info.

Comment: Reading all this again I would revise my answer to suggest still using [graphvis](http://www.graphviz.org/).  It has support for .dot files.  I read something into this I think when I answered or otherwise failed to understand the question.  If graphvis was too slow then I think the overall implementation is not reasonable.  Need to rethink the workflow.  I'd be curious to know what OP ultimately used.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts on this!